Fourier transform of modified Bessel function of second kind $K_0(b\sqrt{a^2-\omega^2})$
Prove the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}K_0(b\sqrt{a^2-\omega^2})e^{-i\,c\, \omega}d\omega=2\pi \cdot \frac{\cos a\sqrt{c^2 - b^2}}{\sqrt{c^2 - b^2}}
\end{equation}
The related integrals from the book 'Table of Integrals, Series and Product' by Gradshtein and Ryzhik



But using all of these reference integrals, I have got the result in form of complex exponential but there is only cosine term in the result.
And also I have used the transformation relations
\begin{equation*}
    K_{\nu}(z)=\frac{\pi}{2}i^{\nu+1}H_{\nu}^{(1)}(iz)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
   H_{\nu}^{(1)}(z)=\frac{2}{\pi}(-i)^{\nu+1}K_{\nu}(-iz)
\end{equation*}

Did the specific parameters you used in one of those results met the conditions given in the book? Btw, what is $b$?

Sorry my mistake, I have added b in edited version.

Shouldn't there be $a$ on the right-hand side as well then?

My bad typing mistake!

I don't believe the Fourier transform converges at least for some values of $a$ and $b$. What are your assumptions on the parameters $a$ and $b$?
